# Copying a source sheet to another workbook where source sheet name changes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy the 2nd sheet from Workbook 2 into Workbook 1 (an open workbook from which I run the macro).

The name of the second sheet changes from time to time.

The code copies the second sheet, under the assumption that the name never changes.

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook

Dim wb2 As Workbook
folder = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel.xlsx (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & "Excel.xls (*xls), *xls", 1, "select wb2")
Set wb2= Workbooks.Open(Filename:=folder)

Sheets("2nd sheet").Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "renamed sheet 2"
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

I tried to rename the second sheet of wb2 before copying, but that didn't work.

```
'wb2.Sheets(2).Select
'ActiveSheet.Name = "2nd sheet"
```

Comment: If the name is liable to change but it is always the second sheet that you want to copy, couldn't you simply change `Sheets("2nd sheet").Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(1)` to `Sheets(2).Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(1)`?

Answer (score 2):

I may not be understanding your issues correctly, but if the name of the second sheet is liable to change, but it is always the second sheet that you want to copy, the following could achieve that:

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook: Set wb1 = ThisWorkbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Path = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel.xlsx (*.xlsx), *.xlsx," & "Excel.xls (*xls), *xls", 1, "select wb2")
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(fileName:=Path)

wb2.Sheets(2).Copy After:=wb1.Sheets(1)
ActiveSheet.Name = "renamed sheet 2"
wb2.Close SaveChanges:=False
```

Comment: @noobaccountant please could you mark my response as an answer, if it has helped? Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Refer to `Sheets("2nd sheet")` as its Excel sheet name (e.g. `Sheets(1)`).